# Restrict Less than < and Greater than > characters in textbox using javascript or Jquery or Regular Expression validator

Tags: javascript, regex

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" MaxLength="95" Width="95%" Height="20px"  onKeypress="CheckExpression(event,this.id)"></asp:TextBox>
```

And function code is:-

```
function CheckExpression(evtobj, id) {

    if (evtobj.keyCode === 60 || evtobj.keyCode === 62) {
        alert();
        evtobj.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: simply remove `alert()` or give it some value. Eg.: `alert('character is not allowed')`.

Comment: alert is only for checking that keycode is matching or not.but  when i am pressing shift + "." for > sign it is key code is not matched.any alternate for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following approach, it will prevent inserting > and < sign.

```js
  function myKeyPress(e){
    var keynum;
    if(window.event) { // IE                    
      keynum = e.keyCode;
    } else if(e.which){ // Netscape/Firefox/Opera                   
      keynum = e.which;
    }
    if(keynum==62 || keynum==60)
        e.preventDefault();
  }
```

```html
<input id="txt" onkeypress="return myKeyPress(event)" />
```

Comment: any other options using javascript because page is quite secure we are not using jquery library.

Comment: @Margijoshi I have updated the answer using simple javascript only

Comment: Thank you..for your help

Answer (score 0):

**It's quite late but following solution will work for you.**

```
<textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="3" 
maxlength="250"placeholder="Enter message or question here"></textarea>
```

// Restrict user to enter less than and greater than (<>) symbol using javascript.

```
let commentBox = document.getElementById('comments');


commentBox.addEventListener("keypress", e => {
      let charCode = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keyCode;
      console.log(charCode); // You can see the code of character 
      if (charCode == 60 || charCode == 62) {
            //prevent default behaviour
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;  
        } 
    });

// Restrict copy & paste in text area.  
commentBox.addEventListener("paste", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;  
});
```